# Installing ubuntu-desktop on ubuntu server doesn't work?

Tags: 14.04, server, .desktop

I installed ubuntu server 14.04 perfectly well.
I made an

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and after

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

I reboot my machine I can access to the login page and put my username and my password.

And after my machine freeze !! and I don't know why ? and how to solve my problem ?

Is it really possible to install ubuntu-desktop on a server ? I tried 3 times and every time the same result freeze after login page.

I really need help ?

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F2 to access the normal console again, log in, and investigate - run `ps auxfw` to see what processes are running, read the log files in `/var/log`, etc.